# Understanding utl_http package

Tags: oracle, plsql

What exactly does the "begin request" function of utl_http pakage return ?

For example , the following code snippet :

l_http_request := UTL_HTTP.request('http://www.google.com', 'POST', 'HTTP/1.1');

What will it return to the variable l_http_request which of type "UTL_HTTP.req" ?

The oracle page says :

"Begins a new HTTP request.UTL_HTTP establishes the network connection to the target Web server or the proxy server and sends the HTTP request line"

What exactly does it mean by sending the HTTP request line ? Does it mean that it passes the http request line in the variable "l_http_request" ?

Will it return the static XML of the loading page of "google" , with the XML containing the description for the "textbox" and the big "Google" poster with its color information ?

If yes then , will the XML so obtained when opened with web browser open a page which looks like the loading page of Google ? What do the other two parameters to the function signify ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_http.htm#CHDIAFFA

Comment: @OldProgrammer : As I have mentioned in the question , I have been through that page , and have attached the line that was written about it . So , I did not understand what it meant by sending the http request line .

Comment: @OldProgrammer : So could you help me in understanding what it means by sending http request line ?